# How to integrate a Flowchart/Activity diagram function in my C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, charts, workflow, workflow-activity

I would like to integrate an activity diagram as in the picture below into my own application but with predefined image objects instead of the customizable rounded rectangles and with arrows...

How can I do that in Visual Studio with C# ?

[image]

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind spending some cash, you can always try something like [Flowchart.NET](http://www.mindfusion.eu/flowchart-net.html), which should suit your needs.

If an off-the-shelf solution is not in your ballpark, you'll have to write your own which I'm afraid is not a trivial task.

Comment: Well, I want to code it myself...Any idea about where to start?